# Visual C++ Express. Вопрос

Tags: visual-c++

Привет! Возможно ли сделать полноценную программу в экспрес версии visual c++ какие там ограничения и есть ли они?

Comment: Можно сделать полноценную программу, инфа 146%

Comment: Ограничения связаны не с компилятором, а с работой больших команд/компаний, плюс часть сопутствующих инструментов. Например, до VC++ 2015 профайлера в облегченных вариантах не было как такового...

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто 
[Сравнит express и Professional можно тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8)

А ныне 
[Professional vs Enterprise vs Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/compare/)